# Multiple values for the 'scope' property in a manifest.json file.

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am working on an existing application with legacy code base. While I would love to see the entire app converted to a PWA some day, for now my plan is one page (one url) at a time. For this, I know that the "scope" property is going to be my best friend for some time. While I can pass "." as a value to the property and treat all the routes as PWS, but as I mentioned earlier, that's not the plan. Hence, below is not an option for me.

```
{
  "scope" : "."
}
```

For now, I plan on covering only two routes under the PWA scope, "list page" and the "details page". Hence I would have preferred something like below to work, but it did not.

```
{
  "scope" : [
              "/list",
              "/id/details"
            ]
}
```

Any suggestion(s)?

Answer (score 5):

> The scope member is a string that represents the navigation scope of this web application's application context.
>
> https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#scope-member

It will not support an array of multiple values.

An option would be to use the scope `/pwa/` (or similar) and as you migrate sections of the app redirect `/list` to `/pwa/list`, etc.